# Compound condition in C: if (0.0 < a < 1.0)

Tags: c, if-statement, expression, conditional-statements

I recently noticed that the following expression compiles in my compiler (Clang):

```
float a;
if (0.0 < a < 1.0) { ... }
```

Does this do what I expect? I would expect that it evaluates identically to this condition:

```
if (0.0 < a && a < 1.0) { ... }
```

If it is so, since when and with which other compilers it is possible to write conditions in this short form?

Comment: thank you all, but don't post +1 time the same answer :)

Comment: You are welcome, but don't post +1 time the same question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chaining Bool values give opposite result to expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939077/chaining-bool-values-give-opposite-result-to-expected)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because of left-to-right associativity of `<` operator the expression condition `(0.0 < a < 1.0)` means  `((0.0 < a) < 1.0)` ==  `1 < 1.0` **or** `0 < 1.0` depending on value of `a`.

So no, its not identical to `if (0.0 < a && a < 1.0)` (perhaps you might confusing from Python compassion rule) but in C it will be interpenetrated  as I explained above.

A difference you can observe in an example --- `0.0 < a < 1.0` == `true` when `a` == `0.0`,  where as `(0.0 < a && a < 1.0)` == false, for `a` == `0.0`, below is my code (read comments):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print_(int c){
    c ? printf("True \n"):
        printf("False \n");
}
int main(void){
    float a = 0.0f;
    print_(0.0f < a < 1.0f); // 0.0 < 0.0 < 1.0f == 0 < 1.0f == True
    print_(0.0f < a && a < 1.0f); // 0.0f < 0.0f && ... ==  False && ... = False
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
True 
False
```

Check its working @[Ideone](http://ideone.com/6gnJS1)

Comment: @MrTJ  I wanted to share a link here, But Sorry the site is not working like 500 error. :( .. I will post a link as after some time.

Answer (score 11):

> Does this do what I expect?

No, it does

```
(0.0 < a) < 1.0
```

and `(0.0 < a)` yields `0` or `1`. So you end up having `0 < 1.0` or `1 < 1.0` evaluated.

Note that in some other languages it does what you expect.

For example in Python,

```
a < b < c
```

is called a *chained comparison* and it is equivalent to:

```
(a < b) and (b < c)
```

Comment: ...and furthermore `0 < 1.0` evaluates to `1`, while `1 < 1.0` evaluates to `0`. So the complete expression is equivalent to `!(0.0 < a)` (which, incidentally, is not equivalent to `0.0 >= a` because of the way that the special floating point value `NAN` works).

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what I expect?

No as it is very simple. `<` operator is having a `left to right` `associativity` it check as follows

```
(0.0 < a < 1.0 ) is simply

(0.0 < a) < 1.0
```

in second form

```
int main()
{
        float a = 8.4;
        if (0.0 < a && a < 9) //same as ( 0.0 < a) && (a < 9)
        printf("x");
}
```

o/p=x

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can think in this way(just for fun):

```
if(0.0 <a < 1.0)
```

==>

```
if((0.0 <a)<1.0)
```

think :

if `0.0 < a == true`, then `(true <1.0) == false`!

else if `0.0 < a == false` ,then `(false <1.0) == true`!

So I can translate `if(0.0 <a <1.0)` to `if(!(0.0<a))`

Interesting , right?