# Difference between if('A' <= e <= 'Z') and if (e >='A' && e <= 'Z')

Tags: c, conditional-statements

Both of these are logically the same but they don't work the same way :

```
if (e >='A' && e <= 'Z')
```

and

```
if('A' <= e <= 'Z')
```

the first line of code works right but the second one does not. Why?

Comment: ` 'A' <= e` is a boolean expression 
in your second line you try to compare boolean expression with a latter Z

Comment: Related [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17878632/3049655), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32219809/3049655), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5939077/3049655)

Comment: Math syntax is not the same as C syntax. The 1st version is correct and the 2nd is nonsense. Never make the mistake of thinking C is rational or  intuitive.

Comment: @Lundin: well done on finding a dupe for this - out of interest what did you search for ?

Comment: @PaulR I remembered answering the very same question myself few weeks back.

Comment: @Lundin: ah yes - that's a useful short-cut - I came to the conclusion that SO probably needs a regex search capability in order to find tricky dupes like this one.

Answer (score 6):

The <= operator is left associative so your second one is actually

```
if( ('A' <= e) <= 'Z')
```

'A' <= e   is a bool which will be 0 or 1 so your statement I believe is equivalent to:

```
if (0 <= 'Z')
```

or

```
if (1 <= 'Z')
```

Comment: Probably? It *will* be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 4):

Your second expression is equivalent to

```
if (<bool> <= 'Z') { ... }
```

where `<bool>` could be 1 or 0. It behaves so due to a priority of the operators. First, comparsion `'A' <= e` occurs. And then the result of this comparsion (that could be only 0 or 1) is compared to 'Z'. And it always leads to true, because 'Z' is always greater than 0 or 1.

Comment: You could point out that both `0` and `1` are less than `'Z'`, so the second predicate will always be true

Answer (score 3):

The `<=` operator is left-associative, so the second snippet is equivalent to:

```
('A' <= e) <= 'Z'
```

Which evaluates to `1 <= 'Z'` if `'A' <= e` or `0 <= 'Z'` otherwise. Both `0` and `1` are less than or equal to `'Z'`, so this is always true.

Answer (score 2):

To explain a little further, it will be evaluated something like this.

```
 if( ('A' <= e) <= 'Z')
```

So, first `('A' <= e)` will evaluated, then the result will be compared to `<= 'Z'`.

The reason behind this is because `<=` operator is left associative.

Answer (score 2):

In C, the operator is `+,-,==, >=, <= and so on`. Take a look in [C Relation Operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm)

So, In `if('A' <= e <= 'Z')`, C can not allowed `variable <= variable <= variable`

That's why second line can not work.

It work, if you can use:

```
if( ('A' <= e) <= 'Z')
```

Because The `<=` operator is left associative

> In condition, all are boolean operation 0 or 1. So, when you compare
>   in C with this operator, they return 0 or 1. So, In your first
>   statement, work correctly because if( bool && bool). But, in second
>   statement, The <= operator is left associative. Condition do not
>   determine with this statement because at a time <= operator occur two
>   times and can not deter mine which is taken. This ambiguity can not
>   work second statement.

Comment: Whats difference between both statements ? Take a look on @haris  answer you both contradict then .

Comment: Those operation are left associative

Comment: You say that the `<=` operator is left associative, yet you mention earlier that *C can not allowed variable <= variable <= variable*. What gives?

Comment: @SakibAhammed  No , I am talking about you say  *second line can not work *  in you   answer and then introduce same line with brackets and say this will work . Well that line will be evaluated as with brackets due to associativity . So what's the difference .

Comment: In condition, all are boolean operation 0 or 1. So, when you compare in C with this operator, they return 0 or 1. So, In your first statement, work correctly because if( bool && bool). But, in second statement, The <= operator is left associative. Condition do not determine with this statement because at a time <= operator occur two times and can not deter mine which is taken. This ambiguity can not work second statement.