# 3 Condition On If Block

Tags: c++

I'am translating from C++ code to visual basic and there is a code on c++

```
    if(a!=b!=c)
    {
       ..........
    }
```

I tried on this code with some C++ compilers but couldn't get same results. What does these 3 conditional if means?

Comment: if (a != b || a != c || b!= c)

Comment: @X-_-FARZA_D-_-X - That is not what the conditional means.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5939077/5740428, except not reproducible.

Comment: ***What does these 3 conditional if means?*** The simple answer is it does not do what you wanted.

Comment: It means the person who wrote the code doesn't know how to use C++ correctly.

Comment: It is absolutely critical that if one's task is to translate a program from language X to language Y, the very first mandatory step is to learn language X. Trying to figure out how each line in language X works, by running keyword searches, will not be very productive.

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried on this code with some C++ compilers but couldn't get same results"? Do you mean you've tried the code on different C++ compilers and got different results? This shouldn't happen; the code is of course very bad but still legal. Or do you actually mean "I tried this code with some **Visual Basic** compilers but couldn't get same results"?

Comment: @Caravansary - Perhaps this is the time to start panicking? If you got this code form someone who doesn't know C++, just imagine how many *other* bugs the code might contain...

Comment: I noticed that if all `a`, `b` and `c` and `bool` variables, than the expression has a reasonable sense: it is exclusive OR of the three operands (`XOR(a, b, c)`). Otherwise it is doesn't make sense and is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the same as `if ((a!=b) != c)`. Assuming `a`, `b`, and `c` are integers, then if `a` and `b` are equal, then that's the same as `if (c != 0)`, otherwise it's the same as `if (c != 1)` (thanks to `bool` promotion to integer).

Not a very useful thing to write, but legal.

Comment: I thought the evaluation for that expression went from right to left? But I think it's the same either way.

Comment: bool promotion to integer not work for Visual Basic i have to use AND, OR to make the same if condition.